# Focus to a particular repeater control item

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one update panel inside that one repeater control. Again repeater is inside div which has `runat='server'` property. Which has bound fields like
Name - As label
Address - As Textbox
Comments - As Textbox

I have to focus the particular record based on condition.like if name is 'John' i should get focused and scrolled to that record inside repeater.I have written login inside ItemDataBound event of repeater control which has code snippet like -

```
TextBox txtComments = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtComments");
txtComments.Focus();
```

Please suggest any solution it's not working for me.
Thanks!!

Comment: That's not enough of an example - are you testing to see if "name is John" (or whatever) before executing these two lines ?

Comment: Actually this not the condition i am checking its just temp thing ,i am comparing id when i select record from grid i am storing that id inside session variable and then it compares with records to be bounded with repeater control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in you page and see if it works

```
Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback = true;
```

combining you code it becomes

```
TextBox txtComments = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtComments");
txtComments.Focus();
Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback = true;
```

Comment: Its working fine for Firefox and Chrome but having issue for IE-10.Could you please help me out.!